# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить данную задачу на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Определить функцию WordN(AnyString, n), возвращающую n-е слово строки S (под словом понимается набор символов, не содержащий пробелов и ограниченный пробелами или началом/концом строки). Если количество слов в строке меньше n, то функция возвращает пустую строку.

Comment: а ваши старания можно увидеть?

Comment: Что **конкретно** надо объяснить? Где сложности?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @АлександрСычёв, здравствуйте. Когда в течение 8-ми часов пытался решить данную задачу, то я не предполагал что вообще буду просить у кого-то совета, всегда справлялся самостоятельно, поэтому многочисленные неудачные попытки просто удалялись. В данное время у меня очень много времени уходит на обучение и написание дипломной работы, да и с JavaScript познакомился меньше недели назад, поэтому в достаточной степени изучить теор. часть не получилось. Уточню: я не просил готовый код, мне достаточно было бы текстового ответа с **подсказками**, например, на какие методы обратить внимание при решении.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, добрый вечер. Надеялся получить **подсказку** или **совет**, которые бы помогли разобраться. Где возникают сложности? Пока, к сожалению, практически везде, т.к. с языком знаком всего несколько дней. Но уважаемый человек внизу показал пример кода, разберусь с методами, которые там были применены.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function WordN(anyString, n) {
  var words = anyString.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim().split(' '); 
  //уберем лишние 
  //пробелы, а затем разобьем строку на массив 
  return words.length < n ? '' : words[n];
}
```

Comment: Код работает не правильно

Comment: @SwaD, какие ваши доказательства?

Comment: @NowhereMan Для строки `' 123 456 789 ылдовадод оыдваоыв   дыоа ыв   оадлыовады '` остаются начальный и конечный пробел как элементы массива. При вызове функции с параметрами `WordN('1 2 3', 3)` получаем undefined, хотя ожидаем 3

Comment: @SwaD, да, для таких входных данных оба замечания корректны.   Для исправления первого можно использовать функцию `trim` для удаления лишних пробелов, для второго следует изменить проверку индекса, чтобы также не был равен длине массива.

Comment: @NowhereMan Комментарий адресован автору ответа с призывом исправить... Вы ему уже подсказали как )

Comment: @Sergey Ryabov, большое спасибо Вам! Обязательно разберусь.